# Apple Studio Display brightness seemingly at maximum when connected to Windows10 laptop

Tags: windows-10, mac, display, multiple-monitors, hp-elitebook

A recently-purchased Apple [Studio Display](https://www.apple.com/studio-display/) works correctly when connected to a MacBook Pro via the monitor's Thunderbolt port.

However, if I connect the monitor to a HP Elitebook (Windows 10 enterprise; 20H2) using its, sole Thunderbolt port, the monitor's brightness appears to be at its maximum value. The brightness setting in the `Display` setting has no effect on the external monitor, but does change the laptop's brightness.

The monitor is set to `Duplicate these displays`.  Changing it to `Extend these displays` has no effect.

I've notice that I can "reset" the brightness to an acceptable level by following these steps:

- disconnect the monitor from the Elitebook
- connect it to the MBP
- reconnect the monitor to the Elitebook

Is there a better way to set the monitor's brightness?

Relevant: [Brightness adjustment for Studio Display with Windows 10 laptop through Thunderbolt 3](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253754346)

Comment: I assume you have updated the firmware of the display? This seems like a intentional functionality or intentionally not following display standards.

Comment: Yes it was updated to version 15.5 (19F77).

Answer (score 1):

Yep it is possible - but it isn't all that straight forward!

I have a Surface Book with USB-C and Thunderbolt 3. I love using my Apple Studio Display with it, webcam, audio, mic, everything works. To get the ability to adjust the brightness you have to install the Windows BootCamp utility which Apple provide.

(All these commands need to be ran from a windows command prompt which has Admin access)

1. Install Python 2.7 (this is needed for the utility which downloads the Apple software) https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/
2. Download 'Brigadier.exe' (this is the tool which grabs the Apple binaries) https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier/releases/tag/0.2.4 (remember where you put it)
3. Open a command prompt and switch to where you downloaded Brigadier.exe to (I put it in "c:\users\alan\display" so I typed "cd c:\users\alan\display")
4. Type Brigadier.exe --model MacPro7,1 (make sure you maintain the capitalisation)
5. On the root of your C:\ drive you should have a folder that says "BootCamp-[something or other]
6. In your command prompt, type msiexec /i C:\BootCamp[whatever-version]\BootCamp\Drivers\Apple\BootCamp.msi
7. Restart, you should have the bootcamp utility installed now. It's a small grey diamond in your system tray.

Comment: Didn't work:

`.\brigadier.exe --model macpro7,1
Using Mac model: macpro7,1.

Couldn't find a Boot Camp ESD for the model macpro7,1 in the given software update catalog.`

Comment: The capitalisation needs to be the same --model MacPro7,1 not --model macpro7,1

Comment: @Craig did this work at the end of it? Seems to still work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to achieve this. Brigadier is only supported on Macs. In other words it is useful when you installed windows on a Mac (e.g. an Intel based mac).

Your only viable choices are:

- Return the display and get something similar from other brands. Although there is no display on the market that has the exact same capabilities, specially that most other brands refuse to produce 5k displays, helping push thousands towards Apple products.

  - [LG UltraFine 5K Display (27MD5KL-B)](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27md5kl-b-5k-uhd-led-monitor)
  - [Huwawei MateView](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/monitors/mateview/)
- Wait until someone figures it out